# How do I change graphics drivers in 13.10?

Tags: graphics, 13.10, system-settings

Where has the option to install proprietory drivers gone in 13.10? It used to be an option in system settings,  but I can't see it there any more.

Comment: Search the dash for and open "Software and Updates" (or something similar, but I think that's it). The last tab is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It's now under **All Settings > System > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**

[image]

Comment: When I choose one of the other drivers and then click apply, my choice is reverted after a second or two... Is there some way to see why this is happening?